# Positive antonym of a "Fall Guy"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe an impostor who is in cahoots with the actual person whose identity they are assuming, and they benefit from it.

In this case, I'm talking about "conspiracy" theories about the authorship of Shakespeare's work, where people think some educated or upper-class person actually wrote the works, instead of William Shakespeare.

If that were true, then Shakespeare would benefit from this false attribution, being credited for such masterpieces. This would be contrary to being a "fall guy", "scapegoat", etc. where the false identity harms the imposter.

What word or phrase would describe such a person?

Comment: The most obvious is 'beneficiary', http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beneficiary

Comment: Damn you beat me to it @chaslyfromUK, I was about to post that as an answer...

Comment: You could say one was playing [prince to the others pauper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Prince_and_the_Pauper).

Comment: @MarvMills comments should never preclude answers.  They should inform them.  If chasely was prepared to offer that as an answer he would have done so.  Feel free to answer and use any comment as a source.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I dare say that if chasly had thought it was a good fit, he would have posted it as an _answer_.  Note that Thesaurus.com and Power Thesaurus don't offer a single antonym to _scapegoat_. Feel free to be informed by more senior contributors.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth before you jump to that conclusion, and encourage others to, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

Comment: How can 'beneficiary: a ​person or ​group who ​receives ​money, ​advantages, etc as a ​result of something ​else' be a close fit for '... a word or phrase to describe an impostor who is in cahoots with the actual person whose identity they are assuming, and they benefit from it. In this case, I'm talking about "conspiracy" theories about the authorship of Shakespeare's work, where people think some educated or upper-class person actually wrote the works, instead of William Shakespear. If that were true, then WS would benefit from this false attribution, being credited for such masterpieces'?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something more specific than 'beneficiary', if such exists. Something with like specificity to "fall guy".

Comment: OP asks for an antonym for 'Fall Guy' (UD: A person who is left with the blame for a crime, regardless of whether they were involved or not), not 'benefactor'. 'Beneficiary' is perhaps the word nearest in meaning to the opposite of 'fall guy', but is still a country mile off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term "front man" is apropos here.  The term refers to someone who is the public face of some operation actually conducted by others.  The front man, as the acknowledged (but false) leader of the operation is given the credit for the operation's results.

Consider the 1976 Woody Allen movie *The Front*, in which Allen portrays Howard Prince, a restaurant cashier of no particular literary talent who happens to know a screenwriter blacklisted as a communist during the McCarthy period in the US.  Prince agrees to submit the blacklisted man's work under his own name.  The ruse is so successful that that other blacklisted writers ask him to be their font man, and he's soon putting his name to their work as well, thereby making an undeserved name for himself as an author.

One possibly-confusing drawback is the term "front man" also refers to the leader of a musical group, meaning a musician who literally does stand in front of the other musicians.  In this case, the font man is an actual part of the music making.

Comment: I think context would make it clear whether the front man is a conspirator or a band leader :)

Comment: @user1359 Hmm.  That gives me a plot idea that Woody Allen could use for his next movie.  Would you like to be the front man for it?

Comment: I sure would :D

Comment: @user1359 I'll have my people get in touch with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a **figurehead puppet master**

- A "figurehead" is a person who is head of a group, company, etc., in
  title but actually has no real authority or responsibility. Synonyms:
  "straw man", "front man".
- A "puppet master" is a person, group, or
  country that covertly controls another. for example, *the
  puppetmaster behind the current administration*

Edit: in many cases, "figurehead" or "front man" may be omitted.

.

Comment: I think 'front man' is good : )

Comment: I think just *puppet* would be better; a *puppet master* is the one in the shadows pulling the strings, quite the opposite of OP's intended usage.

Comment: @Kevin: Following your remark, it seems that I really misunderstood the question :(. The first paragraph of User1359 relates to a *usurper conninving with the "victim" of identity theft*. The third paragraph refers to a *counterproductive imposture*.